# How to add onto a list in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, list, firebase, addition

I am trying to add data to a Firebase list that I have and I feel I am close.

My database is set up like this.
[image]

```
public class AddRestaurantActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText newRestaurant;
    private Button addBtn;
    private Button homeBtn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_restaurant);


        DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final DatabaseReference mRestReference = mRootRef.child("restaurants");

        newRestaurant = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addrestauranttext);
        addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addrestaurantBtn);
        homeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HomeButton);

        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String newRestaurantName = newRestaurant.getText().toString();

                mRestReference.getRoot().setValue(newRestaurantName);
                newRestaurant.setText("");
            }
        });
```

Is the code I have so far and when I use this it doesn't work. The problem is setting the new item. Right now it completely replaces my database because of the mRestReference.getRoot().setValue(newRestaurantName); code that is in. I need to find a way to add a new restaurant so that it doesn't replace everything that is already in the database. refer to the picture of the database to see how it set up. It is very simple with only one attribute called name.
I am new to android and coding in general so any help would be great.

Comment: Please be more specific than "it doesn't work."  Is there an exception or other error message?

Comment: I tried to add more detail. Does that help at all?

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes, change it like this.

```
addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View view) { 
            String newRestaurantName = newRestaurant.getText().toString(); 

            DatabaseReference newResturantRef = mRestReference.push();

            newResturantRef.child("name").setValue("Taco Bell");
            //also store the key of student, so that you can refer it later
            newResturantRef.child("studentKey").setValue(newResturantRef.getKey());
        } 
    });
```

Let me know, how it goes.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much. the only thing is that the child that is set to 1 needs to be a different number so that they can enter multiple options. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: See Frank Van's comment. you can achieve it by creating Push value.. that is always different

Comment: I understand you are a beginner in firebase, I suggest you learn more about firebase by checking online tutorials. Because, what you are asking here is very basic. You don't get lucky get answered these basic questions every time.  
I started from here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGCjwl1RrtcTXrWuRTa59RyRmQ4OedWrt